# Adding the input layer - units with a decimal

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classifier

I took the course Machine Learning A-Z from Udemy and am trying to apply what I learned in the tutorials.  Theye taught us in the "Adding the input layer" portion of an ANN that the units is based off of the input_dim.  Normally the "units = (input_dim + 1) / 2".  In the dataset that I am working with my input_dim=754.  (754 + 1) / 2 = 377.5.  Should I use 377.5 or should I round up or down to a whole number?

```
#Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=377.5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=754))
```

Comment: It does not make a difference it is just an approximation..no offence but i suggest you take a better course which will strengthen your basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round up or down to a whole number. Keras documentation specifies that units should be a positive integer, and I'm not sure what a fractional unit would even mean. Does this work when you try to run it?

Comment: I have tried it with a whole number and it works, but I was unsure if you could use a decimal.  You answered my question.